# How to fetch record from two tables specify column name based on second table row records

Tags: sql-server

I need query which fetch records from two tables but column name should be based on records in second table.
Details are below

My first table

```
Emp Table
emp_id      emp_name
  1           Abc
  2           XYZ
  3           PQR
```

My second table

```
Salary Table
id  emp_id   month   salary
1     1        1      4000
2     1        2      3000
3     2        1      5000
4     2        2      4500
```

I need output like,

```
emp_id    emp_name     jan    feb 
  1         Abc        4000   3000
  2         XYZ        5000   4500
```

I am able to achieve this by using left join but for every month I need to add it in query like,

```
select e.emp_id,e.emp_name,j.month as Jan,f.month as Feb from emp e 
Left Join salary j on e.emp_id=j.emp_id and j.month=1    
Left Join salary f on e.emp_id=f.emp_id and f.month=2
```

Above work for me But which is not feasible. I have master table for month also.

```
Month Table
 id     Name
 1      Jan
 2      Feb
 3      March
 5      April
```

I want fetch record for for specific month currently for (Jan & feb).

Please help me achieve this faster way.

Comment: Can you please post the master table for month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    e.emp_id,
    e.emp_name,
    [Jan]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  1 THEN s.salary END),
    [Feb]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  2 THEN s.salary END),
    [Mar]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  3 THEN s.salary END),
    [Apr]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  4 THEN s.salary END),
    [May]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  5 THEN s.salary END),
    [Jun]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  6 THEN s.salary END),
    [Jul]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  7 THEN s.salary END),
    [Aug]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  8 THEN s.salary END),
    [Sep]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] =  9 THEN s.salary END),
    [Oct]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] = 10 THEN s.salary END),
    [Nov]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] = 11 THEN s.salary END),
    [Dec]   = MAX(CASE WHEN s.[month] = 12 THEN s.salary END)
FROM Emp e
LEFT JOIN Salary s
    ON s.emp_id = e.emp_id
GROUP BY
    e.emp_id, e.emp_name
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485435)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Felix, Thanks for quick response. 
I have one question: What if salary is string like ($4000), which aggregate function should I use? If I removed Max it gives an error.

Comment: Using `MAX` is okay.

Comment: If I want to replace Null with blank space?

Comment: Add an `ELSE` part in the `CASE` expression. `... ELSE '' END`